# sublime text 2 php build - php installed - system unable to find file

Tags: php, build, sublimetext2

Been struggling with this for weeks and read everything I can find on it but no solution. I have PHP version 5.6.17 installed verified by accessing a basic php file from my browser/localhost. Below is the error message I receive when testing a basic php script by running it in Sublime Text with a PHP build setup.

> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>   [cmd:  [u'C:/php/php5.6.17/php.exe',     u'C:\Users\James\Documents\Responsive Riven Web\contact.php']]
>   [dir:  C:\Users\James\Documents\Responsive Riven Web]
>   [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS    Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Syste    m32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management  Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine     Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm]
>   [Finished]

This is my build code:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.6.17\\php.exe", "$file"]
}
```

My PHP folder is saved directly into C. So the path should be c:/php

Can someone advise me exactly what line of code I need to use in my build to correctly run PHP through Sublime Text 2? I appreciate there have been a couple of posts on this topic but none of them have helped me solve this problem.

Comment: The error message does not match the build system you've shown. The build system is using a `php.exe` located under your `C:\wamp` folder, yet the error message shows that the `php.exe` used was under `C:\php`.

Comment: What would the solution be?

Comment: Fixed it... So simple! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction